# EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception on accessing name property of EspDevice class

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, wifi, provisioning

I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception on accessing name property of EspDevice class. I need to access deviceName which is a private property, and name is causing this error. Can somebody help me to sort this issue out. Thanks

[Bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEAtF.png)

Answer (score 0):

**NSLog** takes `NSStrings` but **os_log/print** takes Swift `String`s.
 They are sadly not the same type. So your NSLog throws the EXC_BAD_ACCESS

As you obviously expose your code to objective-C its anyway better to work with NSStrings to avoid those pitfalls.
You could also use a cast to force the interoperable behaviour.

```
let mystr = "Samsung TV"
let nsStr = mystr as NSString
```

or

```
var devices = [NSString]()
```

But i guess the problem is even deeper.
Set a Breakpoint to line 22 and watch what happens with the properties.

Answer (score 0):

NSLog is function with undefined number arguments. And to identify parameters types and count it uses format string.
So if yours device name will have `%@` it will expect that you have passed in call stack second parameter. Accessing invalid parameter will lead to bad access.

You should use `NSLog("%@", device.name)` instead